# Multi-module app, access multiple R files from one source file

Tags: android, android-resources, multi-module

I'm refactoring my Android app to multi-module structure and now I'm facing the issue where I need to access R files from different modules in one source file (feature-specific strings and global strings and colors).

Is there some better way to do it then to address the R files by full paths with package names? Maybe some other approach to resource structuring? It isn't a big of a problem, but the code becomes a bit uglier and less readable.

Comment: if you do the moduling right, all of the modules resources would be accessible from the main modules R file

Comment: For example I have some module-specific strings that I don't want to expose to the whole app, so they will be in my.app.feature.R file, but all global strings are in my.app.base.R file... For now I don't see how they may be accessible from the main R file... Am I missing something?

Comment: AFAIK, they will be accessible from the main R, if you want to hide them it will be a new question